# Align even three div tables with multiple images- table 1 and 3 have 3 pics all same size, table 2 has different size pic

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-tables, assign

Pics to show exactly what I am trying to do:

[Link to Images](http://testnow.us/divimages)

The first image is an item I created in fireworks but I want to be able to manipulate the images in dreamweaver. This is NOT homework!! The first image is the way that it should look and the second image is how it is turning out. For the life of me I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I know it is probably a simple thing that I am overlooking but have spent way to much time on this and can't seem to focus clearly.

CSS:

```
#header {
width:750px;
height:341px;
margin-left:25px;
display:block;
}
#tableleft {
clear: right;
float: left;
width: 128px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top:10px;
 }
#tablecenter {
margin-left:165px;
clear: both;
float: left;
width: 410px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
#tableright {
clear: left;
float: left;
width: 128px;
margin-left: 600px;
margin-right:10px;
margin-top:10px;
}
```

html

```
<p align="center"><img src="images/SmWhitepic.jpg" alt="" width="118" height="87"     /></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center"><img src="images/SmWhitepic.jpg" alt="" width="118" height="87" /></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center"><img src="images/SmWhitepic.jpg" alt="" width="118" height="87" /></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please show your html code i have understand your problem by seeing your image show me your html code please and let me know

Comment: <div id="header">
      <div id="tableleft">
        <div align="center">
          <p><img src="images/SmWhitepic.jpg" width="118" height="87" /></p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p><img src="images/SmWhitepic.jpg" width="118" height="87" /></p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p><img src="images/SmWhitepic.jpg" width="118" height="87" /></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tablecenter"><img src="images/LgWhitepic.jpg" width="410" height="242" /></div>
      <div id="tableright">

Answer (score 0):

Delete this `clear` from every ID style ( if the widths of the divs are good )

Comment: sorry i am new to this site so forgive my messed up entry of the code. I deleted the "Clear" from each ID Style and that worked great, now I just have a problem with the right div being to close to the center one. I tried adjusting the margins but no luck.

Comment: never mind, I changed the right table to float right and solved the problem. Thank you so much, I just needed a fresh pair of eyes on this.